# Как поменять application Id в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

В Android Studio пытаюсь поменять application Id с skidok.kz.asilarman на skidok.kz.shop - пишет

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'skidok.kz.shop' что может быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, что вы добавляли в проект `google-services` плагин, а это значит, что [на сайте Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add) вам нужно сгенерировать новый файл **google-services.json** с новым `application Id`, и заменить им старый файл в проекте (в каталоге app/ или mobile/ проекта Android Studio).

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам надо заменить файл `googleplay-services` - при его генерации вы указываете пакет приложения и после изменения либы play-services смотрят в старый файл и не могут найти заявленный там пакет. Пересоздайте и замените этот файл